# Get all hashes exists in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm have hashes in redis cache like:

```
Hash         Key    Value
hashme:1    Hello   World
hashme:2    Here    Iam
myhash:1    Next    One
```

My goal is to get the Hashes as output in the CLI like:

```
hashme
myhash
```

If there's no such option, this is ok too:

```
 hashme:1
 hashme:2
 myhash:1
```

I didn't find any relevant command for it in Redis API.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: HLEN is quite useful, for anyone in the future, checking if the hash itself exists or not

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `SCAN` command to get all keys from Redis. Then for each key, use the `TYPE` command to check if it's a hash.

**UPDATE:**

With Redis 6.0, the `SCAN` command supports *TYPE* subcommand, and you can use this subcommand to scan all keys of a specified type:

```
SCAN 0 TYPE hash
```

Also never use `KEYS` command in production environment!!! It's a dangerous command which might block Redis for a long time.

Comment: Can you further explain what is the set of commands I need to execute ?

Comment: The [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command is used for incrementally iterating keys in Redis. With this command, you can get all keys in Redis. The [TYPE](https://redis.io/commands/type) command is used for getting the type of a key. Please see the doc for more details.

Comment: This command only returns the first 10 found. Not the equivalent of keys *.

Comment: @FredTheWebGuy You can scan in a loop with the cursor it returns. Check its documentation for detail. However, never use `KEYS` in production, since it blocks Redis for a long time especially when there're lots of keys in the database.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of redis (and others K/v stores) is for you to build an index. The database won't do it for you. It's a major difference with relational databases, which conributes to better performances.

So when your app creates a hash, put its key into a SET. When your app deletes a hash, remove its key from the SET. And then to get the list of hash IDs, just use SMEMBERS to get the content of the SET.

Comment: That is a nice workaround, but I don't want to write code in my app just for this scenario.

Comment: Its not a workaround its how you have to do it. You are responsible to construct and manage your own indexes typically using a SET - so if you need to be able to retrieve all HASH of some type relevant to your app (eg users) you need to keep a SET called users into which you add/remove your HASH keys as required

Comment: Both answers may be valid, depending on the context. We do not have enough context info in the question to know which one is better (by example: how any keys are they in the DB? Is it in production? etc.)

Answer (score 3):

```
keys *
```

is work for me. you Can try it.

Comment: keys is bad! its supposed to be only used for debugging and should be avoided on production server

Comment: as the other comment said, "keys" is considered a `dangerous redis command`. It blocks until finished.  This can mean outages...

Answer (score 1):

connection.keys('*') this will bring all the keys irrespective of the data type as everything in redis is stored as key value format

Comment: Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets.

Answer (score 0):

for redis in python, you can use below command to retrieve keys from redis db

```
def standardize_list(bytelist):
    return [x.decode('utf-8') for x in bytelist]

>>> standardize_list(r.keys())
['hat:1236154736', 'hat:56854717', 'hat:1326692461']
```

here `r` variable is redis connection object